# "Refused to frame" error with 2 deep iFrame only in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy

I have a website that hosts an iFrame that hosts another iFrame inside it, so the iFrames are 2 deep.  When I run on Chrome, I get the below error and the lowest level iFrame does not display, though the middle layer does show.  When I access it using Firefox, everything works and the console does not log any errors.

Chrome console error:

```
Refused to frame 'site1' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' site1 site2 site3".
```

As you can see from the error message, I have all levels in the chain referenced as frame ancestors in the header, so I cannot come up with any more sites to list there.  Additionally, if I try to open the middle website in Chrome without the top most parent, everything works, displaying the lowest level iFrame.  Can anyone offer any hints as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was all my fault.  I was not understanding the differences between frame-ancestors and frame-src.  I did not even realize there were two different sets of values.  Once I got that straightened out by using frame-ancestors to list the parent domains and using frame-src to list the child domains, everything worked the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

> When I access it using Firefox, everything works and the console does not log any errors.

Firefox has a [bug with logging](https://csplite.com/csp/test221/#bug_Firefox_no_warning) `frame-ancestor`'s errors in the console.

> Chrome console error: Refused to frame 'site1' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"frame-ancestors 'self' site1 site2 site3"`.

It's weird because Chrome definitely [allows nested iframe](https://csplite.com/csp/test355/#test) when in the `frame-ancestors` directive is specified all host-sources of upstream DOM frames.

Maybe among yours "*site1 site2 site3*" the `data:` source is presented?
Or some nested iframes publishes `X-Frame-Options` header?

Yeah, `frame-ancestors` directive is complicated and bugged, but I think there is some hidden details in you issue.